# How to get Google to consider what appears as object in the right column of SERP

Tags: google-search, search-results

I am trying to get Google to use and show the proper item in a SERP. Yes, I know no one knows the algorithms but I am just wondering what basic things can be done to play by the rules and get Google to better consider what appears in the right column of a certain SERP.

Take this real example:

Do a search on "t-rex group". The Google SERP is shown below.

Why does Google show the rock band "T Rex" vs. a nicely formatted "Google My Business" block as it does for hundreds of other sites out there?

What specific steps can one take to properly ensure that all bases are covered by to get proper consideration. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this question has been asked in various forms already on Pro Webmasters.